# Footer that sticks to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

Hi I have a css issue as I am trying to stick a footer to the bottom of the page but it only sticks it as far down as the viewport goes and not the bottom of the document.

Can somebody help me understand why this is please?

My css and html is pretty simple although after reading lots of examples and trying things out I still cant get this to work. I dont want my footer inside the wrapper, rather outside of it and I also dont want to set height:100% on the wrapper.

My html looks like below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
... some content
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

And my css:

```
html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position:relative;
}

body {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, tahoma, arial, serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;           
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    height: 25px;        
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    width: 1024px;
    padding: 6px;
    clear:both;
```

}

is it possible to do this with the footer outside of the wrapper?

I thought that setting position absolute on the footer would mean it would be positioned based on the body or html as they are the next elements up with a position:relative but bottom:0 seems to just be the bottom of the viewport even though the wrapper div extends far past this with lots of content.

The consequence of this is that when there is a lot of content within the wrapper the footer actually sticks mid way up the page as bottom is calculated as the bottom of the viewport.

Thanks

Comment: It is not inside the wrapper. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tfRuy/

Comment: google for sticky footer :)

Comment: Not necessary to add "position" to all the classes.

Comment: Why don't you want it inside the wrapper?

Comment: Adam I didnt want it inside the wrapper because the wrapper has some additional css such as back ground colour and a border and I didnt want the footer inside of this. I am thinking of reworking my html now.

Comment: Sowmya what is it that youre showing me? I looked at your example which is what I posted.. then I added a div with a height and your example does exactly what mine does..... the footer floats halfway up the content now.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning need not be used all the time. The attribute is meant only for certain cases to specially "position" content.

I think removing

```
position: absolute;
```

from

```
  .footer
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: This just means that now I am back to square one, which is that my footer is at the bottom of the page if the content in the wrapper is large enough, if the content in the wrapper is very small my footer floats half way up the page which isnt what I am after.

Comment: So basically you want the wrapper to stick to the bottom of the page when there's lot of content and the bottom of the viewport when there's little content??

Comment: try `body{min-height:100%}` and keep the `position:absolute` for `.footer`. You footer should position according to body which will be 100% of viewport only when content is less. Hope this helps.

Comment: or set `position:fixed` if you want it to stay at the bottom of the screen all the time.. im unsure about what exactly your after...